# Running resize2fs on /

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I'm trying to resize an ext4 filesystem on a Fedora 11 box.
Using fsdisk and lvm, I was able to grow the partition and 
logical volume containing the filesystem.

When I try to run resize2fs on the device containing the 
filesystem (/dev/sda2 in this case), I get:

"Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda2,
  Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock"

I've tried this from a rescue disk that doesn't have the filesystem 
mounted, no joy.

Maybe resize2fs doesn't know about ext4?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using LVM then you want to resize the filesystem in the LV, not in the partition. Try one of the entries in `/dev/mapper` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you boot from a live cd be sure the lvm package is present (apt-get install lvm2). If so, use vgchange -a y to activate all the volumes. You can now access them under /dev/lvm/ or /dev/mapper/